# Google Hangout in Drupal Site

Tags: drupal, google-hangouts

I'm building a project where I need to implement Google+ Hangouts. I am able to get the Hangout button in my website by which I can start a hangout on air and get the YouTube URL. Using this URL I created views where the live sessions are going on. But the process is manual, means I can have to manually copy the URL link from You-Tube and paste it to get the video.

My question is can I automate the process? i.e when I click the hangout button can the URL be automatically be retrieved and the node is created.
I think it can be done if I can get the hangout ID. But I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your requests are programmable but not automatable. For example, you can use the Hangout button to launch a new Hangout but the user must specifically turn that Hangout into an On Air. From there, you can build a [Hangout App](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) that retrieves the [YouTube ID](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair).